# Django, apache-wsgi - server is serving /js and /css but cannot serve images

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Static catalog structure:

```
website
--css
--js
--images
  --landinpage.png
```

Apache access log:

```
"GET /static/website/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200"
"GET /static/website/images/landinpage.png HTTP/1.1" 404
```

HTML code:

```
<code>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/website/css/style.css"/>

<style>
body {
    background: white url("/static/website/images/landinpage.png");
</code>
```

I can see /static/website/css/style.css being loaded properly (hence 200 server response in apache logs), but when server tries to load /static/website/images/landinpage.png I am getting 404 response.
I have verified file names and location

Comment: How do you server the static files in Apache?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Right now everything is under /var/www/

Comment: show your httpd.conf for Apache same for setting.py in Django pls

Comment: apache conf - http://pastebin.com/DFEBDXrd settings.py - http://pastebin.com/RmbC4W2A

Comment: in ona place you have landinpage and in the other landingpage

Comment: It's landinpage  everywhere. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If static server apache2:**

in *settings.py* add static dir

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

collect static to dir

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

in apache conf add path

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/static/
```

**If dev server.**

Template context processors *settings.py*

```
'django.template.context_processors.static',
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```